# How to display the given table data from sqlserver into crystal report using c# winforms?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am developing a winforms application in 3-tier architecture in the form of 
  connection oriented using system.data.sqlclient namespace.

So in my database i have a ward table, the fields like ward_id,ward_name,
  member_name etc.

So i want to display this on crystal report using c#.

Right click on my project -->Add New Item --> CrystalReports

After selecting it display wizard so i have selected and the next wizard will
  display i.e standard report creation wizard like below.[image]

In this,no items found is shown.

But in Project Data folder--> .NET Objects it shown all my tables like below.

[image]

But the tables are shown in the above pic when i expand actually those are 
  not the fields for that particular table example in my ward table.

The fileds shown like below[image]

My problem is that, how to get my fields like ward_id,ward_name etc. in my
  crystal report.

I am new to crystal report can you solve my issue?

Suppose if i add dataset in my project but in that i need to enter all the 
  columns with relations in dataset object. But my table contains nearly 35 
  fields with relations this is very complex. So, instead of dataset can i get 
  another wary to display data as report in crystal report viewer.

VIS_wardinformation1 is the class in my project;
  tbl_wardinformation is my table in sql server.

Actually in my wardInformation form i have a print button when user clicks on 
  print button i will display total records on form2

In wardInformation Form:

```
form2 f=new form2();

f.show();
```

Then, in my form2 load event:

```
 CrystalReport2 crystalReport = new CrystalReport2();
 DataSet  dsCustomers = GetData();
 crystalReport.SetDataSource(dsCustomers);
 this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
 this.crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

My GetData(): it gives all the records of my ward table:

```
  dt = WLogic.GetInformation();

  ds.Tables.Add(dt);

  return ds
```

So in my ds contains data i used connection oriented architecture.

But in runtime when i click on print button it shows "File NotFound Exception Was 
  Un handled"  "No source available" page is displayed instead of displaying 
  data what is the issue here?

Note: I didn't create dataset means example.xsd file. Instead of this i wrote
  storedprocedure for getting all the records from back end and i called sp from
  front and i have stored the given result into dataset. that's what i did.

Is there any wrong in my approach? please tell?what's the issue?

Thanks

Comment: have you try to create a new connection using the wizard?

Comment: Yes i created now i got all the fields but the records are not displayed in my crystalReportViewer. what's the problem above is my code?

Comment: Thanks it's working for me i add startup mark up in my app.config it's working now thanks.